# FullCalendar show UTC as local

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, fullcalendar, ui-calendar

I am using ui-calendar (fullcalendar.io) and I want to save the dates to the database as UTC and then display them to the user in the current timezone.

```
$scope.uiConfig: {
   calendar: {
        timezone: 'local'
    }
}
```

per [here.](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone/timezone/)

But it still displays a utc moment as whatever it actually is vs converting to local time.

Does anyone have experience using fullcalendar and storing dates in UTC on the server then displaying them in local time on the front end?